# How to redirect any /promotion/* URLs to just /* with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect any requests to mysite.com/promotion/* pages to just mysite.com/*, so a few examples would be:

- mysite.com/promotion/some/page.html would redirect to mysite.com/some/page.html
- mysite.com/promotion/another-page.html would redirect to mysite.com/another-page.html

How can this be done with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it like this:

```
Redirect permanent /promotion/ http://www.mysite.com/
```

I didn't realize that it would automatically work recursively like that, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/promotion/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Won't that just remove promotion from the URL but still serve up the same content? I want to literally redirect users from /promotion/whatever to /whatever.